# Converting JSON date(s) in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, date, angular-filters

I would like to convert dates retrieved from JSON string and format them yyyy-MM-dd. I am using the code below to format my the dates but oddly the dates are returning "12-31-1969" when the JSON string is for example "created_at": "2016-01-26T09:52:31Z" therefore the correct string would be 01-26-2016 not 12-31-1969.

HTML:

```
<li class="mark">Created:</li>
<li class="mark"> {{item.created_at | jsonDate : 'MM-dd-yyyy' }}"</li>
<li class="mark">Updated:</li>
<li class="mark"> {{item.updated_at | jsonDate : 'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</li>
```

Filter:

```
 defaultPage.filter('jsonDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input, format) {
           return (input) ? $filter('date')(parseInt(input.substr(6)), format) : '';
    };
}]);
```

Comment: From a quick glance, seems like an issue on this: input.substr(6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parseInt(input.substr(6))` is unnecessary. From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), the `date` argument to the filter function is described as:

> Date to format either as Date object, milliseconds (string or number)
>   or various ISO 8601 datetime string formats (e.g.
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ and its shorter versions like
>   yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmZ, yyyy-MM-dd or yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ). If no timezone is
>   specified in the string input, the time is considered to be in the
>   local timezone.

In your case, it is in the ISO 8601 string format, so your filter line can just be:

```
return (input) ? $filter('date')(input, format) : '';
```

Here's a fiddle that shows it working: https://jsfiddle.net/ezj2kefL/1/

Answer (score 0):

with:

```
parseInt(input.substr(6))
```

you are returning 0, which is the beginning of the epoch; thus, you get 12-31-1969.

Dates are tricky with Javascript. In my laziness, I rely on the [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) lib.

[Sotch.io - Display Time Relatively in Angular](https://scotch.io/tutorials/display-time-relatively-in-angular) provides an excellent example of what your are attempting, I believe along the very same lines.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_filter_date.asp

nothing to do by JS just do in HTML it self

like `{{item.created_at | date }}` or `{{ item.created_at | date : "fullDate" }}` etc.

Answer (score 0):

The given date string in JSON(2016-01-26T09:52:31Z) seems to be working with the [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) filter available with AngularJS now. However the date string with my JSON was not working and I modified it to get the required output.

Sharing modified filter code below for those who may come here checking like me:

```
app.filter('jsonDate', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
        return function (input, format) {
        return (input) ? $filter('date')(Date.parse(input), format) : '';
    };
}]);
```